# Create div on the fly in asp.net mvc/jquery/javascript

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, html, wizard

I am developing the online test application in asp.net mvc. Where I need the wizard. I found the code to create the wizard [Here](http://worcesterwideweb.com/2007/06/04/jquery-wizard-plugin/). But here are limited divs/para. I don't know how many questions containing in the single test. So it is necessary to create the div for each question on the fly. And as per requirement show them in wizard structure. Also need to know how to pass the List to jquery function so that it will automatically create all these divs on the fly. Please help.

Comment: You don't give us enough detail to answer the question honestly.  Creating divs in MVC is easy, just loop through the items in the Model, emitting a div for each.  In Javascript is easy too (document.createElement("div"), easier yet in jQuery).  Is your question in how to best integrate all this nicely?  Then sample code would help.

Comment: basically, i want to pass the List collection to jquery. for each object in List I want to show a div. but, it must view one at a time, not list of all divs. so need to create wizard like structure.I know about loop the Model. but it generates series of div and all will visible too.getting what i am trying to say ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working perfect for me. For Back button use parameter loadNext(i,iPrevious).

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            $(function() {
                var count = 6
                for (i = 1; i <= count; i++) {


                    if(i < count) {
                    var iNext = i + 1;
                    var iPrevious = i - 1;

                    $("<div id=" + i + "> Step " + i +

                          "<button type='submit' onclick=" + "loadnext(" + i + "," + iNext + ");> Next" + "</button>" +
                       "</div>").hide().appendTo("#parentDiv").fadeIn();


                     }
                    else
                        if(i == count) {
                             $("<div id=" + i + "> Step " + i +

                                 "<button type='submit' onclick=" + "loadnext();>Submit" + "</button>" +
                                    "</div>").hide().appendTo("#parentDiv").fadeIn();


                     }

                    $("#" + i).hide();
                }
            });
            $(function() { $("#1").show(); });
            function loadnext(divout, divin) {           
                $("#" + divout).hide();
                $("#" + divin).show();
            }

        </script>

  <div id="parentDiv">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like [jquery UI accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/) could help?

Comment: Wonderful, really. Thanks for sharing this.but I got created wizard control by code in my answer